# How to run vim from command line and prevent press ENTER or type command to continue

Tags: search, silent-mode

I have a bind that invokes vim on a file with a search term:

This is shell scripting.
`vim $FILE "+/$SEARCHTERM"`

The problem that happens is that **only if** `$SEARCHTERM` appears just once in a file, it seems to be emitting `search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP` and this is presumably causing the opening of the buffer to be interactively delayed with `Press ENTER or type command to continue`.

I just want this not to happen to make the file open to the search term for me immediately.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. `vim some/file '+/some-term'` works fine for me even if `some-term` only occurs once. Can you try with `vim -Nu NONE`? Or  `vim "$FILE" '+exec "norm /" . $SEARCHTERM . "\<cr>\<cr>"'`, if `$SEARCHTERM` is exported?

Answer (score 1):

Providing the argument `"+silent /${SEARCHTERM}"` to vim was my solution. This should be equivalent to running the `:/` search using `:silent /` which does the trick. No need to change how vim normally behaves with searches!